# i'm having a problem navigating through my Scaffolds or screens

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, google-signin

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import './newauth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Welcome());
}

var occupied;
var setter;

class Welcome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeState createState() => _WelcomeState();
}

class _WelcomeState extends State<Welcome> {

  getVisitingFlagsignin() async{
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


  setState(() {
    occupied = preferences.getBool("alreadyVisited");
    print(occupied);
  });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold loginScaffold = new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('LOGIN'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[700],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/applogo.png'),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 152,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/Glogo.png',
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Login',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Michroma'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        handleSignIn(); 
                      }),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Here is where I call my scaffolds. my problem is when the log in butter is pressed, i call the google sign in function from my other dart file which is based from the documentation of flutter and not much has been changed there. i can successfully log in and initialize the state of the app if there is already a user logged in. when the log in button is pressed that's where i hit a wall on how to call my other scaffold and possibly pass some data to it.

```
    Scaffold hompagescaffold = new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Homepage'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(child: Text('signout'),onPressed: (){signOutGoogle();},),
    );
    return new MaterialApp(home: occupied == true ? hompagescaffold:loginScaffold);

  }

    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getVisitingFlagsignin();
  }
}
```

this is my auth.dart file. so when signin button gets pressed, the handlesign in function gets called then runs all the necessary google sign in and firebase authentication gets triggered and after that shared preferences will get called to set my boolean preference to true. the next thing I want to do is to call out my homepage scaffold in order for it to replace the loginscaffold.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

setVisitingFlagsignin() async{
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
preferences.setBool("alreadyVisited", true);
print(preferences.getBool("alreadyVisited"));
}

Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);

  setVisitingFlagsignin();

  return user;

}





setVisitingFlagsignout() async{
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.setBool("alreadyVisited", false);
  print (preferences.getBool("alreadyVisited"));
  }

void signOutGoogle() async{
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  print ('User has signed out');
  setVisitingFlagsignout();
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert and welcome ! I think it isn't very clear what your problem is; could you please provide us with further explanation ? e.g. you could add the content of your `handleSignIn()` method ? Also what exactly happens when you press the signin button and 'hit a wall' ?

Comment: Hi! i'll edit my post :D thankyou for replying.